# Ruby on Rails - How to hide physical image path

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do we hide the physical image path in a rails application. Currently I have the following RoR code to display an image in my application.

```
<%= image_tag("student_pictures/#{@student.admission_no}.jpg") %>
```

Found several solutions to do this with PHP, but I haven't come across a solution in RoR so far. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean?  The image tag will always need a source URI, which is visible from the client.

Comment: Maybe you need some CDN?

Comment: Another option would be to embed your image into the page via css: `#logo { background: url(<%= asset_data_uri 'logo.png' %>) }`. This way your image doesn't have to be publicly available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you ultimately trying to achieve, as far as I know following are the two paths you left with.

1 - show the url (because basically for browser to show the image it should be in a place which can be publicly accessibly, so if you take the source code of the web page you should be able to view the image url and if you post it in the browser url you should see the image)

2 - generate the image on the fly  (I have done this in Java but not with rails)(instead you store the image physically in the disk, you write the image as a byte stream to the browser as and when user requires it)

But if you could tell us what you what to do we might come up with an alternative :)